# Yii2 Behaviors / Scenarios Modify Attribute

Tags: yii2, behavior, scenarios

I have a model "**Product**" that I would like to modify or "mutate"  one of its attributes for, but only in specific instances.

I store attribute, **price** as an integer.  So $1.99 gets stored as 199.

I would like to incorporate this with the **activeForm** in such a way that when getting the price it converts to "1.99" in the field (visually).  But when I submit the form, before validation, it modifies the price from "1.99" to "199".

I'm assuming this will require Behaviors, and specifically attaching a behavior to the model before creating the active form. However, I'm still confused on how to set this up.  I see there is an AttributeBehavior class or I can make my own Behavior class, but I've been having trouble figuring out implementation in this case.

The situation:

```
foreach ($store_item->storeProducts as $i=>$product) {
?>
 <tr>
     <td>
       <?= $form->field($product, '['.$i.']price')->label(false); ?>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <?php 
    $i++;
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: you can use model event **beforeValidate()**  to store $1.99 as 199 and when getting results you can use **afterFind()**  for getting 199 to 1.99

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the database field is of type `int` instead of `decimal`?

Comment: You could simply use a getter/setter

Comment: Yes beforeVaidate() and afterFind() are nice, but I don't want to do this all the time. I only want this to happen when this form is used.  So I would need to pass in a conditional.  The other caveat is that the model is already loaded in an array and the form is in a for loop because I'm updating many things at once.  @topher To answer your question.  When dealing with money converting to int is just cleaner (it's what Stripe does).

Comment: I have given a generic example. Modify it to fit your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a scenario where I check for empty attribute and assign value before saving. Note [owner](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-behavior.html#$owner-detail) returns the Model so that you can access model attributes and functions that are public. Let me know if I can explain anything further

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [   
        [
            'class' => AttributeBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'yourAttrib', 
            ],
            'value' => function ($event) { 
                $code = "N/A";
                if(!empty($this->owner->yourAttrib))
                {
                    $code = $this->owner->yourAttrib; //here change your attribute accordingly
                }
                return $code;
            },
        ], 
        //other behaviors
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a getter/setter, e.g. :

```
public function getRealPrice()
{
    return $this->price/100;
}

public function setRealPrice($value)
{
    $this->price = $value*100;
}
```

And don't forget to :

- add `realPrice` in your model's rules,
- use `realPrice` in your form (instead of `price`).